# How can I connect an Apple TV to an older television?

Tags: appletv, hdmi, video-adapter

Is there a way to connect the latest Apple TV, which only has an HDMI output, to an older television that only has the yellow and red/white inputs for audio and video? This older television has a coaxial input as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the format you want is called composite video, so you might have better luck searching for a HDMI to Composite converter.
RCA is just the name of the connector. For example: 
[http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0080KN18K/ref=redir_mdp_mobile](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0080KN18K)

Answer (score 1):

You're having a hard time determining it cause those "yellow / white" cables are called "RCA" ports, created by one of the first TV makers and ironically mostly sold off to Japanese companies.

Searching for "RCA to HDMI converter" yields a wealth of converters and opinions about the best devices based on the model of TV

such as this article:

http://techchannel.radioshack.com/convert-hdmi-rca-1778.html